# Android Dumpsys - How to obtain power on/off data from a year ago

Tags: android, adb, restart, shutdown, dumpsys

Is it possible to run a command in adb shell, dumpsys perhaps that will show the power on off dates and times from a year ago ?

I have run dumpsys and it has created a huge file with loads, 100's of thousands of records in a file - what text should I search for ?

Comment: Your question may better fit to https://android.stackexchange.com as obtaining power on/off data is not very programming related. On the other hand what have you tried? You can simply search the dumpsys output for dates (in ISO format) and see where it can be found.

Comment: Thanks Robert. I will post on the other channel.  I've searched for shutdown, power, reboot and the datetime strings "2023-02-26 19", "2023-02-26 20" and found some entries, but I don't know whether any relate to a power off of the phone, there's no description as such.